# Implement BotDetect With Angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, captcha, botdetect

We have license of [BotDetect](https://captcha.com/). and I would like to implement this BotDetect with Angular js. I Search in google And I found nothing proper helpful, however, I got [angularjs-captcha](https://github.com/captcha-com/angularjs-captcha) which looks promising but didn't help me.

Here is what I need exactly.

1. page load with Captcha Image
2. User Fill the form
3. User Hit on Submit
4. Using $http request page submit
5. If the response comes success or failure Captcha should be reloaded as per it's working engine.

**Here is My Form**

```
<form ng-submit="Submit($event)">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="datafield">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <span class="red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td class="datafield">
                <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="searchboxmain" placeholder="enter name..."
                    ng-model="Form.Name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="datafield">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <span class="red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td class="datafield">
                <input type="email" maxlength="240" class="searchboxmain" placeholder="enter email..."
                    ng-model="Form.Email" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="datafield">Enter Captcha
            </td>
            <td class="datafield">
                <botdetect-captcha>
            <br />
                <input type="text" id="CaptchaCodeTextBox" ng-model="Form.Captcha"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="datafield"></td>
            <td class="datafield">
                <button class="submitbutton" ng-click="Submit($event)">Submit enquiry</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Form = {
        Name: '',
        Email: '',
        Captcha: ''
    };
    $scope.Submit = function(event) {
        // Here all code
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

I am quite sure there could be other solution instead of using this Angular Captcha but I don't know anyone so, an alternative solution can be accepted.

Comment: It might some jQuery function provided to reload captcha image which I didn't know, using the only jQuery solution I can handle rest of work.

Comment: are you using it with JAVA? Docs says there is only Java supported currently (https://captcha.com/angular-captcha.html#angularjs)

Comment: No, I am using ASP.NET C# (Not MVC).

Comment: From [captcha website](https://captcha.com/angular-captcha.html#angularjs): "Please Note: Currently, AngularJS module is only supported by BotDetect Java, but support in PHP and ASP.NET versions is coming soon." I have personally never used ASP.NET, but it may be possible to create a workaround where you host the captcha on a separate page running MVC. If that isn't an option for you guys, then it looks like you're out of luck for now :(

Comment: This might help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bot Detect](https://captcha.com/angular-captcha.html#angularjs):

> Please Note: Currently, AngularJS module is only supported by BotDetect Java, but support in PHP and ASP.NET versions is coming soon.

However, you should be able to accomplish what you have described in your question via the following guide: [Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)